# I have a weird issue with the camera on apple tv. There is white pixelation that covers the level and only shows a part of it

Tags: unity-game-engine, tvos, apple-tv

[image]There is white pixelation that covers the level and only shows a part of it. This issue started after upgrading to unity 2019.2 from unity 2017.1. I am attaching a screenshot to demonstrate the issue. Can somebody please help. It works fine on iOS but not on apple tv

Comment: Hey! Can you show us a bit of the code that you think is causing this? Perhaps the camera settings? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. The issue is with the post processing. For some reason post processing stack V1 doesn't work on apple tv for Unity 2019. It works on iOS. Now I am not sure if the issue is general or just specific to me.